# Renaming Red Hat Enterprise Linux Network Interfaces

Tags: rhel, network-interface

I have a virtual machine on vmware ESXi 6.0 running Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.2.

I have two network interfaces that I want to be named "eth0" and "eth1" respectively. They were originally named with the prefix "eno..." and then a string of numbers.

I edited the `ifcfg` files for both interfaces by changing the `name` and `device` parameters to "eth0" and "eth1".

I then renamed the `ifcfg` files to `ifcfg-eth0` and `ifcfg-eth1`.

When I run `systemctl restart network` I get an error stating that the connection "eth0" is not available on the device "eno167".

[image]

It appears that the device name needs to be changed somewhere else in addition to the files in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`, where else could I verify that I need to change the network adapter name?

Comment: google udev rules eth0. at my iphone, wont be able to help for a while

Answer (score 3, accepted):

udev changed (ruined) it's interface naming scheme a while back.  One of the easiest ways to get the old method back is to add 'net.ifnames=0' as a kernel parameter in your grub.conf file

Comment: Our build system ended up with both `biosdevname=0` and `net.ifnames=0` to stop these udev hijinks, regardless of whether on olden or newer releases, sigh.

Comment: I put both `biosdevname=0` and `net.ifnames=0` in the grub kernel parameters and then used `ip link` to set the names after rebooting and the network interfaces were successfully changed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Also worth noting if you don't like the new interface naming convention it is possible to name interfaces whatever you like.

In `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` create a file `ifcfg-[desired-name]`

Add:

```
DEVICE=[desired-name]
HWADDR=[mac address of the interface]
```

You can add all the usual settings to this file as well. This will name the interface whatever you like and pairs it up based on the MAC address of your device.

So if you wanted an interface named `ftp-interface` using the interface with a MAC address `00:00:00:00:00:00` and wanted it to have an IP `1.1.1.1/24` you could use:

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ftp-interface
--------------------------------------------------

DEVICE="ftp-interface"
HWADDR=00:00:00:00:00:00
IPADDR=1.1.1.1
PREFIX=24
```

You can find more details about how the naming works on the Red Hat site: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Understanding_the_Device_Renaming_Procedure.html

Answer (score 1):

Centimane's method works also with centos 7 (redhat based).. Big thanks !

I also have in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf  for plugings just plugins=ifcfg-rh , not keyfile.

this is/was the simplest way to change the interface name.. and I googled a lot!

of course NetworkManager will make a new interface so you have to configure it again... like disable dhcp from it.. so don't block your self out.

if you put just mac and new name to the ifcfg file NetworkManager will fill the rest.